# How to properly organize XAML resources in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, resources

I'm having some issues with resource files in my modular application.

I have `Infrastructure.DLL` and some custom controls inside this DLL. Those controls using templates from `themes/generic.xaml`
Issue that I have - Blend doesn't recognize those resources. Visual studio does.

Ideally I'd like to have styles for my cusom controls inside `generic.xaml` and styles for other controls somewhere else in common library that I can reference from my modules.

I also need Expression Blend and VS to work properly.

How do I arrange solution to make it happen?

PS. Important! WPF is different but I'm interested in Silverlight solution

Comment: Did you mean `Themes\Generic.xaml` ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I fuxed post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to create design time resource for your `generic.xaml` in order to let Blend recoganize it. Take a look at [this post](http://adamkinney.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/design-time-resources-in-expression-blend-4-rc/).

In each of your modules, you create a `ResourceDictionary` like this.

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
Source="/xxx.Silverlight.Controls;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Also, in your `.csproj` file, you need to add this. Please note that normally this piece of code is auto-generated by Blend, so if your `ResourceDictionary` is auto-generated, you don't need to do the following.

```
<Page Include="Design\DesignTimeResources.xaml" Condition="'$(DesignTime)'=='true' OR ('$(SolutionPath)'!='' AND Exists('$(SolutionPath)') AND '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'!='true' AND '$(BuildingInsideExpressionBlend)'!='true')">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
</Page>
```

Design is the folder I created for storing my `DesignTimeResources.xaml`. I pretty much have the same structure as yours. :)

Comment: Still doesn't work. I mean it work, kind of. But I still need every view to point to that resource

Comment: You should create a resource dictionary for it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks! Blend didn't want to do it on itself, after I manually edited project file it works like a charm now. I have DesignData folder with design data and I placed DesignTimeResources there as well.

Comment: I had another quick question. Have you looked at: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/09/15/best-practices-for-themes-in-modular-silverlight-applications.aspx ? What is the point of loading resources in code?

Comment: I think in his situation he loads the required references after the main application is loaded, so the code behind is just to pull the theme into the application. However, in my project, I load everything at the start so I won't have to do this. I guess as long as you can see your styles in Blend and be able to the run the application, you don't need to do this. :)

Comment: @katit Would you mind also allocating the points to my answer? Thanks!